# Webbroswer module on beagle bone

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I am trying to get my python script to open a web browser by using the webbroswer module.
However beagle bone just skips through the code. Any help will be appreciated

```
import webbrowser 

url = 'www.google.com'
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `webbrowser.open_new(url)` instead